# Weird jquery/jquery validator bug

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

If i using the official jquery lib the validator (bassistance.de/query-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation) have an annoying bug, if i hit the submit an empty (required) field the validator will display errors, but if i fill the input box the script doesnt validate it again (onkeypress or onblur should oblige to re-validate), only if i click submit again.

Hours later i realized if i using the lib at bassistance the bug dissappear.

Checkboxes and lists works well with both version of the lib.

[Here you can check](http://jsfiddle.net/nU5he/) the form with the original lib.
(Hit submit, and write something to username field)
[Here is the working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/wRTLq/)

Comment: Stack Overflow is for posting questions and answers. What is your question? Are you trying to file a bug report? This isn't the place for that.

Comment: Sorry, my question is whats wrong with the newer lib and and should i expect more bugs with other plugins if i using the latest jquery lib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't "official" in the sense that it's *part* of jQuery. It's a 3rd party plugin.

And there's no mystery here: In the *working* version, you're using jQuery 1.3.2, which is rather old. In the *working* version you're using jQuery 1.6. Presumably the plugin was written against this older version of jQuery. When you use a newer version of jQuery, the plugin isn't working correctly.

There is nothing "wrong" with the newer jQuery library, there is likely a bug in the 3rd party library which was written against an earlier version.